# Cannot Play Audio Consistently in Some Android Browsers

Tags: android, html5-audio

I am unable to consistently play audio files from web pages on my Nexus S (Android 2.3.6).  I have six audio files.  They're in both mp3 and ogg formats.  I have three browsers on the phone that I've experimented with: Browser 2.3.6, Dolphin HD 7.3.0, and Firefox 10.0.2.

All files play every time in Firefox.  In Browser and Dolphin, some of the files play and some don't.  Each time I test in Browser and Dolphin, the number of files that won't play increase, until finally none or only one plays.

Once, I used Android's Manage Applications tool to delete Browser's data and cache.  This also caused the Browser process to stop.  This one time, when I restarted Browser and tried to play to audio files, they all played.  A subsequent attempt using this method did not restore the ability to play audio.

I also tried to play these audio files from the same web page on desktop computer browsers,   Chrome and Firefox.  In both cases, all audio files played every time.

Any ideas on what's causing this inconsistent audio playing behavior?  Another useful answer would be, is there a way to trap the error (if there is one) Browser gets when it cannot play an audio file.

I'm more of a Java/Server-side programmer, so I'm not very knowledgable about a debug approach for this kind of problem in a mobile browser.

Comment: have you had chance to test it on Android 4? I am writing an MP3 player webapp on Android which plays MP3 audio fine on Android 2.3.6 and Android 4..

Comment: Since I and most other people don't yet have Android 4, I haven't tested on it.  (Actually, I don't even think it's available yet for the Nexus S.)  Given that audio works fine in Firefox on Android 2.3.6, I suspect the problem is a GingerBread browser bug.  And that the answer to this question will be a browser specific tweak/work-around to enable consistent audio.  Thanks for your interest:-)

Comment: download the SDK, you can use the emulator to test on any version of Android http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: I'm not sure what that would buy me.  At this time, I want to play audio on Android 2.2.x and 2.3.x, which are about 80% of all Android devices (and probably will be for a while, given that ICS is taking forever to be widely released).  But I'd be interested to see your code, which you say plays MP3 fine.  Maybe I can learn something from the way you manage audio files.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, would you post the code you are using now and i'll show you how i wouod do it, and how to trap errors.. (although the best way to view errors is via logcat in the SDK)